# Графическое отображение дробей

Tags: python

Как в Python можно отобразить графически дробь или дробь и целую часть? Как например отображение графиков в Matplotlib, только с дробями.

Comment: Да как угодно: хоть кружочками и палочками, хоть в классическом варианте. Что именно нужно?

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов нужно нормальное представление дробей и целых чисел, например одна целая одна вторая не вот так 1 1/2 или не вот так 1(1/2) а по людски как в тетрадях пишут, может есть какие нибудь либы для этого, для графиков на сколько я знаю есть, может дроби тоже как то можно отрисовывать

Comment: А куда выводите? На бумагу?

Comment: Ну так где в вопросе это написано? Может вы в консоль выводите, может на веб-страницу, а может и на печать на бумагу. Откуда нам знать. А ответы будут разные.

Comment: Вам просто намекнули, что вывод в python есть не только туда. куда вам надо, но и в другие места тоже.

Comment: Дополняйте вопрос, вставляйте картинку "как надо".

Comment: Ага, а еще, желательно, пишите как уже пробовали и что конкретно не получилось.

Comment: https://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?1\tfrac{1}{2} ?

Comment: [Посмотрите примеры вывода в `sympy`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/printing.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример с использованием [модуля `sympy`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/printing.html):

```
In [1]: from sympy import init_session

In [2]: init_session()
IPython console for SymPy 1.1.1 (Python 3.6.2-64-bit) (ground types: python)

These commands were executed:
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> from sympy import *
>>> x, y, z, t = symbols('x y z t')
>>> k, m, n = symbols('k m n', integer=True)
>>> f, g, h = symbols('f g h', cls=Function)
>>> init_printing()

Documentation can be found at http://docs.sympy.org/1.1.1/


In [3]: from sympy.abc import a,b,c,x,y,z

In [4]: 1/sqrt(a)
Out[4]:
1
──
√a
```

используя функцию `pprint`:

```
In [6]: from sympy import pprint

In [7]: pprint(1/sqrt(a))
1
──
√a

In [8]: pprint(1/sqrt(a), use_unicode=False)
  1
-----
  ___
\/ a
```

Comment: Если по первому варианту в jupyter notebook выводить, то вообще красиво получается: [скриншот](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePS13.png), причем это не картинка, а html.

Comment: @insolor, да, в Jupyter практически все выглядит симпатичнее - просто я предпочитаю консоль ;-)

Comment: @MaxU то что нужно